# How would one make this shape in an HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, crop, geometry, shapes

I'm wonder how you would go about and create a shape similar to this one below in HTML5 Canvas. It's more or less a cropped circle I guess, though my need would render it a synch different.

http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/5198/98359410.jpg

```
context.fillStyle = "#000";
context.beginPath();
context.arc(200,200,100,0,Math.PI*2,true);
context.closePath();
context.fill();
```

Now to crop the booger, I'm perplexed. Could anyone lend me a hand? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';

context.fillRect(200, 220, 200, 100); //Or something similar
```

`destination-in` means, per [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing): *The existing canvas content is kept where both the new shape and existing canvas content overlap. Everything else is made transparent.*

Or conversly

```
context.fillRect(200, 220, 200, 100);

context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';

//Draw arc...
```

`source-in` means: *The new shape is drawn only where both the new shape and the destination canvas overlap. Everything else is made transparent*

Both these methods will end up disrupting other content already drawn to canvas, if this is an issue, use `clip`

```
context.save();
context.beginPath();

//Draw rectangular path
context.moveTo(200, 220);
context.lineTo(400, 220);
context.lineTo(400, 320);
context.lineTo(200, 320);
context.lineTo(200, 220);

//Use current path as clipping region
context.clip();

//Draw arc...

//Restore original clipping region, likely the full canvas area
context.restore()
```